# Azure DevOps - Pull Request Git "Next steps: Manually resolve these conflicts and push new changes to the source branch."

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have created a branch named dev.

I have done a pull request to send dev code to master, when I do this pull request it tell me:
[image]

50+ conflicts prevent automatic merging
"Next steps: Manually resolve these conflicts and push new changes to the source branch."

Where do I go from here? I just want all the dev branch to replace whatever is in master. I see no options to resolve these conflicts.

Comment: I do have a "Complete" button but it is grayed out.

Comment: Manual merging is not possible within the VSTS environment. You should merge the master branch into your dev branch, resolve the conflicts, commit and push.

Comment: Well that answer my question. So should I merge the branch instead of doing a pull request?

Comment: With a pull request you give other developers the opportunity to review your code and give feedback. Once this review has been completed you can then merge the code into the master branch.

You should not merge the dev branch to master locally and then push it, unless you've agreed with collaborators that this is how your process works.

The solution is to merge the master into your dev branch and solve the conflicts, as I indicated in my previous comment.

Comment: It seems in my environment (I am not allowed to update the source branch), one has to re-get all source branch files and just start over )-:

Comment: I don't have permission to push to master from my local machine, only to review and approve pull requests (even my own) - that's the only way to merge into master. All the solutions here rely on local work. Where to from here?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You will have to do the following on your PC

On branch `dev`

`$ git pull --no-rebase origin master` - This will create a merge commit and you will have to resolve the conflicts in the files which are changed both on dev and master. `git status` will show the list of files with conflicting changes.

After resolving conflicts, commit all the changes and push your branch. After that you should be able to complete the PR.

FYI: **--no-rebase** makes sure that a merge is done even if the pull behavior is overwritten to default to rebase.

[Help link for more details](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/)

Comment: **Better Link to Documentation** - The following is a link to Azure DevOps documentation "Resolve merge conflicts" which provides both an explanation about what merge conflicts are along with instruction on how to resolve using command line or Visual Studio.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 5):

Since you need to keep the files version on `dev` branch (keep the source branch while changing files in target branch `master`), so you should make changes on `master` branch to resolve the conflict files, and be sure you have permission to push changes to `master` branch.

You can use below options:

#### Option 1: merge directly

In your local repo, you can execute below commands to merge `dev` into `master` branch while keeping the conflict files version as the `dev` branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev -X theirs
git push origin master
```

And in the existing pull request you created, it will shows the branch has been merged. So you can abandon the pull request.

#### Option 2: still merge via pull request (resolve conflicts on master branch)

You can use below commands to resolve conflicts in `master` branch:

```
# In yout local repo
git checkout master
git checkout dev -- .
git commit -m 'replace master branch version by dev for the conflict files'
git push origin master
```

While the changes in existing pull request won’t be updated if new commit(s) pushs to the target branch (master). And you can find the similar report [Pull request diff does not update when a commit from the PR is merged to the target via another branch](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/51306/pull-request-diff-does-not-update-when-a-commit-fr.html).

That means, the pull request in the web page still show the conflicts. You should abandon the existing pull request and reactivate (or create a new one) to merge dev into master branch.

Comment: I try option 2, and get "Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch."

Comment: Pushing to `master` is a poor recommendation.  There is no reason to push onto master to keep your changes. You have all of your commits on the dev branch.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a `rebase`. Had to walk through all the commits and apply my changes - they were pretty extensive, renaming namespaces & method names, etc. This then let me continue to do a `Pull Request` in the Azure DevOps portal. Actually, I could just Refresh changes for the existing `Pull Request` and the auto merge conflicts were resolved.

Merging the code did not resolve the issue, only `rebase` worked.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps to fix the problem

1. Open git change
2. From branch dropdown, found your destination repo.. But don't click it yet [image]
3. On your destination repo, right click and select 'merge into current branch'
4. When 'merge into current branch' has done, you will see list of files that having conflict. Stage them or delete it when you don't need it or fix the problem causing conflict then stage it.
5. When all files with conflict has been staged, sync.
6. Your problem should be fixed at this point

Edit :
I am having the same problem lately.
Here my steps to fix the problem:

1. On branch dropdown on 'Git Change', select destination branch (in my case dev)
2. On branch dropdown, right click on source branch (in my case dev002) then select merge to current branch
3. List of conflict will be shown. Delete or fix the file, then stage and sync
4. Problem has been fixed
5. After step #4 then select your source branch again to continue working

Answer (score 0):

I had a merge conflict on a feature branch.

```
1. switched to the development branch and I completed a pull getting the current code base
2. git pull --no-rebase origin /feature/2 
3. from team resolved the merge conflict by manually selecting code between 
the conflicting file then pressing "accept merge"

4. push the changes to the git repository
5. complete a pull request into development
```