# Azure Devops development to master merge issue

Tags: git, azure, tfs, azure-devops

I have a problem very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371911/azure-devops-pull-request-git-next-steps-manually-resolve-these-conflicts-an) but the solutions aren't working.

I am attempting to merge my development branch into my master branch in TFS Azure DevOps with a Pull Request and receive this error -

> 24 conflicts prevent automatic merging
>
> file1.js    ----- Added in both
>   etc...
>
> Next steps: Manually resolve these conflicts and push new changes to
>   the source branch.

Both development and master have Branch Policies that require changes to be done through a Pull Request.

I have previously merged development to master successfully (and then made more changes in development that I want to get into master), maybe this is why I get this error?

I attempted to merge master to development locally and created a new PR into development for these changes, but the change-set I pushed is empty.  Now when I do this:

```
git checkout development
git pull origin master
```

I get

```
From https://MYTFS-SERVER/DefaultCollection/PROJECT/_git/REPO
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48375272/210757) suggests these commands to kick off the merge, but doesn't this just pull the latest from the server into the master branch?  I don't get it.

I could attempt to merge master to dev again:

```
git checkout development
git merge master
// resolve conflicts, commit, push
```

But I think it will bark about not being a PR, and I swear I already did this when I got the empty change-set, and I don't want to create a bigger mess.

Where should I go from here?

On a side note, I plan on ditching the development branch and just working straight from master once I get this resolved.

Comment: I was able to get my changes in by reverting my previous dev -> master merge and doing it again, however dev now says 3 behind 15 ahead; it was 2 behind 15 ahead prior to this so I think I would have the same problem next time if I wasn't ditching the development branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert master from previous Pull Request merge

**1,From your completed pull request page, find the previous merge from dev to master.**

[image]

**2,In the prompted window, select master branch as target branch to create a revert branch.**

[image]

**3,After you create the revert branch. You will be suggested to create a new Pull Request. Then create a pull request to merge the revert branch to master branch to revert master to its original state.** After complete remember to check delete the revert branch in the `Post-completion options`

[image]

**4, After the merge was complete. Abandon and then reactivate your original develop-to-master pull request. The confliction error should be gone.**

Hope it work for you.

Comment: Thanks; I did that to get a long running feature branch into my development branch. What I really don't get, is how a two branch strategy (like "Git Flow") is supposed to work in Azure DevOps with branch policies that require Pull Requests.  Maybe cherry picking is how you are supposed to do it?  Or maybe Azure is just geared for a one branch trunking strategy.

Comment: One of Git Flow strategy's cons is that it can create long running branches that might be hard to combine to main branch. It tested further on this issue, and found if i merged dev to master with 'squash' merge type, It would always cause conflicts on next merge from dev to master, while other merge types worked good. I wonder if you squashed merge dev to master?

Comment: Yes, I did, and that was my experience as well.

Comment: If that was the case, I think reverting master branch from previous PR merge would be a better option. I updated above solution. Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this issue was solved but still want to share what worked for me. As complex as the issue sound, all I had to do it running this git command "git pull origin master" into my local branch. This helped me finally find the conflict in my local branch and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
Git Push
```

Then

```
Git pull origin master
```

and the branch was up to date with master